# How to use thmtools features with accented variables in proof titles?

Tags: accents, thmtools

I'm using the `accents` package to put accents over variables in math mode. The accented variables work fine in `amsthm` theorems, as demonstrated in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{accents}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}
Proposition text.
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}
Proof with accented variable $\accentset{\star}{I}$ in text.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof with accented variable $\accentset{\star}{I}$ in title.]
Proof text.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

If I load `thmtools`, however, I start getting errors from `\accentset` commands that appear within proof titles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{accents}

\declaretheorem[name=Proposition]{prop}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}
Proposition text.
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}
Proof with accented variable $\accentset{\star}{I}$ in text.
\end{proof}

% without this proof, the document compiles
\begin{proof}[Proof with accented variable $\accentset{\star}{I}$ in title.]
Proof text.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to use the theorem repetition feature from `thmtools`, but I have accented variables in some proof titles. Is there any way to make this work?

(I'm happy to use a different package for theorem repetition. I'm hesitant to change the way I put accents over variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently (still) a fragile command so can be made safe with `\protect`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{accents}

\declaretheorem[name=Proposition]{prop}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}
Proposition text.
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}
Proof with accented variable $\accentset{\star}{I}$ in text.
\end{proof}

% without this proof, the document compiles
\begin{proof}[Proof with accented variable $\protect\accentset{\star}{I}$ in title.]
Proof text.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! This was great motivation to finally learn a little about fragile commands. How did you figure out that `\accentset` is fragile? (And does that method work in general?)